# При наведении мышки на один элемент менять класс другому?

Tags: angular5, angular-directive

я создал Directive.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHover]'
})


export class HoverDirective {

    @HostBinding( 'class.under' ) isunder = false;



    @HostListener( 'mouseenter' ) OnEnter(){
      this.isunder = true
    }

    @HostListener( 'mouseleave' ) OnLeave(){
      this.isunder = false
    }

}
```

При наведении мышки на перый **nav**

```
  <nav appHover> nav 1</nav>
  <nav> nav 2</nav>
```

к нему применяются стили

```
.under
    text-decoration: underline
```

Как сделать чтобы при наведении на первый **nav** стили применялись к второму **nav** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `native API` типа `document.querySelector.classList.toggle`, но это как-то не по Angular'овски. Просто повесьте обработчик события на первый `nav`, а второй `nav` задекларируйте как шаблонную переменную:

```
<nav (mouseover)="onMouseover()" (mouseleave)="onMouseleave()">nav 1</nav>
<nav #nav>nav 2</nav>
```

И в компоненте:

```
@ViewChild('nav')
public nav: ElementRef<HTMLElement> = null;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

public onMouseover(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.nav.nativeElement, 'under');
}

public onMouseleave(): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.nav.nativeElement, 'under');
}
```